# Does Captain Barnacles sing the Creature Report "live"?

Tags: octonauts

At the end of each episode of *Octonauts*, we can hear the Creature Report being sung by Captain Barnacles. However, after Barnacles says "Facts:", the camera (usually?) cuts away from him, and we don't see him again until the the main portion of the Report has concluded (during the dance break and the outro).

For example, keep your eye on Barnacles during this S01 E01 ("Octonauts and the Whale Shark") Creature Report:

Is there any evidence to indicate whether Captain Barnacles actually sings the Creature Report "live"; or whether that part of the singing is a pre-recorded audio portion of the Create Report video?

Comment: It's an animated show. What are you talking about?

Comment: Given that each "report" is identical, save for what's on the bluescreen behind them, I suspect we'll never know.

Comment: I VTC'ed because, first of all, what exactly are you asking? Second of all, I could make an argument for this to be closed as off-topic, as well. I really don't the Octonauts is science fiction...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath - They have fictional underwater technology; underwater stations, a floating HQ and all sorts of other fishy tech that puts this well within the scope of science fiction

Comment: @Valorum - That is pushing the definition of science fiction to _well_ past its limits. Just because something is fictional doesn't mean that it is science fiction! So are we calling Seasame Street Sci-Fi? Or Between the Lions? What about Dora the Explorer? Oh, yeah, Spongebob Squarepants? Thomas & Friends?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath - I think you'll find that you're mistaken. Sesame Street isn't Sci-fi because it doesn't consistently have a science-fictional setting. Dora probably does qualify (at least as far as her visiting the fabled (and as far as I'm aware non-existent) [Lost City of Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dora_and_the_Lost_City_of_Gold))

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath - Oh, and the people who make it certainly think it is; "*Based on the richly imaginative books by Meomi and beautifully animated by Brown Bag Films, Octonauts combines eye-popping visuals, submersive humor and pulse-quickening action to transport young children into an undersea universe, unlike anything else in pre-school TV. **The series is classic sci-fi, where our heroes encounter real undersea creatures that are just as exciting and unusual as make-believe aliens – it’s Star Trek meets Jacques Cousteau for kids!*"** - https://silvergatemedia.com/show/octonauts/

Comment: I fail to see how this is unclear. If you watch the video, you can clearly see (and hear) the change in tone and pitch when they switch over to the "facts" section of the presentation

Comment: @Valorum how can anything be "live"? There aren't real cameras filming real actors. The whole thing is a pre-recorded animation. The question makes no sense.

Comment: @OrangeDog - The singing is live *[in-universe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-universe)* whereas the images on the screen are clearly pre-taped *in-universe*.

Comment: @Valorum - Why isn't Sesame Street sci-fi? Are you trying to tell me that there are furry muppet-monsters running all over the place? No, that's fictional. According to your logic, that would make it sci-fi.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath - We've discussed this [pretty extensively on Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy). The general rule of thumb is that anthropomorophic animals/monsters don't make a property on-topic unless there's a reason to assume that the show isn't just treating them like animal-shaped people. That said, questions about monsters would be in the scope of [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e)

Comment: @Valorum - Yeah, but also, see [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/683/are-childrens-literature-and-cartoons-for-children-on-topic)...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath - "*If it's merely creative creatures, even if they exhibit unusual abilities, it shouldn't be on topic.*" which this isn't. These aren't just creative creatures, they also have science-fiction tech.

Comment: @Valorum - I was thinking more of the second answer... "I think the line is pretty straightforward: would a serious fan of the science fiction or fantasy genres consider spending any amount of effort digging into the details of a children's cartoon? If the answer is yes, it's on-topic. If the answer is no, it's off-topic."

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath That's a really bad way to look at it. Valorum will dig into anything if it means rep points!

Comment: @Skooba - I've twitted at the creator, the studio and the chap who wrote the original book

Comment: @Valorum I believe the past tense is twat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posed this question to Anahita Tabarsi, [Brown Bag Films](https://www.brownbagfilms.com/labs/entry/octonauts-creature-report-octopus)' Head of Digital Marketing. She has confirmed that while the singing and dancing portion of the report happens live each time, the "facts" element of the presentation is ***pre-recorded by Barnacles before the Octonauts get there***.

> **Q.** *When Captain Barnacle[s] is giving the "creature report" and all the facts come up on the monitors, is he also singing about the facts or is that bit pre-recorded (by him) before the other Octonauts get there?*
>
> **BrownBagFilms:** *Hey there! Good question - the songs are all recorded in advance :)*

Presumably this allows the Octonauts to access the 'facts' at a later time, should they need to recap during the mission.

Comment: I just can't even

Comment: @OrangeDog - there's always an answer...